Can I customize my Allure report like adding steps, softassertion using Ready API tool with groovy scripting
I am using Ready API tool for automating Rest API and In my test case I added groovy script for adding extra validation. I can able to generate the report using Allure , which is straight forward. However, I want soft assertion and step description as well as logging all comparison result in my test report. Is this possible, because when I added @Step, @Description it did not log in my report. Also did not find any soft assertion.
Appreciate any help on this !
I added below commonutil method to log the report in Allure report
@Step("Log Comparison for {0} property {1}: API Value = {2}, DB Value = {3}, Result = {4}")
    static void logComparisonToAllure (String itemName,String property, Object apiValue, Object dbValue, String comparisonResult) {

        // String resultDetails =  "Property: "+property +"\n" +
        //                         "API Value: "+apiValue +"\n"+
        //                         "DB Value: "+dbValue +"\n"+
        //                         "Result: "+comparisonResult
        // Allure.addAttachment("Comparison Result - "+ property ,"text/plain", resultDetails)
        
        Allure.addAttachment("${itemName} - ${property} - API Value","text/plain", apiValue?.toString() ?:"null")
        Allure.addAttachment("${itemName} - ${property} - DB Value","text/plain", dbValue?.toString() ?:"null")
        Allure.addAttachment("${itemName} - ${property} - Result","text/palin", comparisonResult)
        

        if (comparisonResult == 'Fail') {
            assert "Comparison failed for property: ${property}\nAPI Value: ${apiValue}\nDB Value: ${dbValue}"
        }
        
    }

    @Step("Log failures for {0}")
    static void logFailuresToAllure(String itemName,List<String> failures) {
        // Allure.addAttachment("Comparison Failures", "text/plain", failures.join("\n\n"))
        // assert false: "Some comparisons failed. Check details in the Allure report."
        failures.each {failure ->
            Allure.Step("Failure Detail"{
                Allure.addAttachment("${itemName} Failure Detail", "text/plain", failure)
            })

        }
        assert false: "Some comparisons for ${itemName} failed. Check details in the Allure report."
    }

Also, I did not  find any way to execute my test case if any one of my test comparison failed.
